# GitHub.com heading links - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, github, utf-8, encode

Does anyone know what is proper and official algorithm that GitHub.com uses to encode fragment_id links for inner headers?

(I hope that is not considered anymore as tooooo broad question).

I reverse engineered way how GitHub flavoured Markdown formats links to content headers. It seems to be quite odd way, so I guess I did something wrong. Maybe you have clue how to improve it (except chaining, which is skipped here for readability of the steps).

First of all I found that such a string
`` 1.2.3-a Łukasz_testing? header `special characters`;.,links How+they%20 behave ``
will be encoded there as
`123-a-%C5%81ukasz_testing-header-special-characterslinks-howthey20-behave`.

I recreated same result with:

```
function(string) {
    string = string.replace(/[A-Z]+/g,function(v) { return v.toLowerCase(); });
    string = string.replace(/[^a-z0-9-\s\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+/g,'');
    string = string.replace(/[\s\t ]+/g, '-');
    string = encodeURIComponent(string);
    return string;
}
```

But it looks quite clunky. Any ideas how close is it to the original?

Comment: You can chain all those `replace`.

Comment: `string.replace(/[A-Z]+/g,function(v) { return v.toLowerCase(); });`, not just `string.toLowerCase()`? Also this is off-topic. You might try http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for a review of working code. Perhaps it should be migrated to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @meagar it can't be so because they don't lower case non ascii alpha-numeric characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @elclanrs, chaining looks more concise:

```
function(string) {
    return encodeURIComponent(string.replace(/[A-Z]+/g,function(v) { return v.toLowerCase(); })
                                    .replace(/[^a-z0-9-\s\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF\w]+/g,'')
                                    .replace(/[\s\t ]+/g, '-'));
}
```

I wouldn't look for a "wiseass" implementation (such "one regex to rule them all"), this implementation is simple and readable - which would make it easy to maintain.